# How to disable a specific function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, web

I'm working on a Wordpress project and the site looks fine when viewed from desktop but on mobile it scrolls to top every time you try to scroll. so i want to know how to completely disable the `scrollTop()` jQuery function.

Comment: Just don't call it in the first place?

Comment: You got the question wrong. You want to stop the scroll function working device specific. Try searching for such codes. It's easy

Comment: @FluffyKitten you don't understand my question i am not the one who worked on the project. i was just brought up after it was finished. and i don't know where it is being called.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to debug the project instead of disabling the function? It may or may not affect the project entirely.

Comment: I understand it can be difficult to maintain code that you have inherited, but trying to add a hack to like this is going to make it impossible to maintain in future. The existing code is written to perform a specific action and adding more code somewhere else to "block" those actions is a very bad idea - especially if you are preventing the default functionality of standard functions. You'll end up with code that no one knows what its doing and are more likely to introduce even more bugs.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
delete $.prototype.scrollTop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hook this function to customize its behavior

```js
let originalScrollTop = window.scrollTop
function myScrollTop() {
  // Do something you like
  originalScrollTop() // you can decide whither call it or not
}

window.scrollTop = myScrollTop
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to prevent default link click behaviour (which is: make a request of the resource defined by the href attribute value and load response) in your click event by doing this:

```
$("a").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    // display your menu
    // and do what's required
});
```

Usually people also suggest to return false; from your handler, but that's not necessary. Still you can do that just before the closing curly brace of the click event handler function.

Comment: you forgot to check yourself if `evt.defaultPrevented` is true.
Always check if `evt.defaultPrevented` has been called before.

Comment: there is no anchor tag here. the page just scrolls up when you scroll down

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to locate the scrolling function and disable it manually (comment-out). Use CTRL+SHIFT+F in Chrome to search in page resources for `scroll` or `scrollTop` keywords and check javascript files.